# In Ansible, is there a way to force variable values to integer?

Tags: yaml, ansible, jinja2, botocore

I'm trying to use ecs_taskdefinition module for Ansible (v2.0), and I think I'm stuck in the basic Ansible YAML gotcha.

As per the example for the module, if I provide integer values for `cpu` and `memory`, this works as expected:

```
- name: "Create task definition"
  ecs_taskdefinition:
    containers:
    - name: simple-app
      cpu: 10
      memory: 300
      essential: true
      image: "httpd:2.4"
      portMappings:
      - containerPort: 80
        hostPort: 80
```

Although, I would like the `memory` and `cpu` to be templatable. So that I will be able to use same container definition for different environments.

```
APP_ENV: "test"
test:
  containers:
    simple_app:
      memory: 1920
      cpu: 2560

- name: "Create task definition"
  ecs_taskdefinition:
    containers:
    - name: simple-app
      cpu: "{{vars.get(APP_ENV).containers.simple_app.cpu | int}}"
      memory: "{{vars.get(APP_ENV).containers.simple_app.memory | int}}"
      essential: true
      image: "httpd:2.4"
      portMappings:
      - containerPort: 80
        hostPort: 80
```

With above, I get error from the botocore API:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].memory, value: 1920, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'int'>, <type 'long'>
Invalid type for parameter containerDefinitions[0].cpu, value: 2560, type: <type 'str'>, valid types: <type 'int'>, <type 'long'>
```

Is this fixable without having to update the Ansible module to actually try to convert these values to integers?

Comment: As I have not found any way to address this from the playbook; suggesting this feature to this specific module. https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/pull/1715

Comment: I test the variable|int in ansible 2.0.2 and works fine.  I think that the error is the quotes " "  please delete quotes before and after {{vars.get(APP_ENV).containers.simple_app.cpu | int}} and try again.

Comment: @RaulHugo I don't think it will work without quotes, as per [Ansible doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas). It says, ```Further, Ansible uses "{{ var }}" for variables. If a value after a colon starts with a "{", YAML will think it is a dictionary, so you must quote it, like so:

foo: "{{ variable }}"```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working in Ansible version 2.1.1.0. If you can't get it to work, a possible solution is to define the variables a the top level of the dictionary and *not* using the `int` filter…

```
vars:
  APP_ENV: test
  simple_app_container_cpu: 2560
  simple_app_container_ram: 1920

tasks:
  - name: Create task definition
    ecs_taskdefinition:
      containers:
        - name: simple-app
          cpu: "{{simple_app_container_cpu}}"
          memory: "{{simple_app_container_ram}}"
```

Note: I used `ram` instead of `memory` because I like how it lines up :)